# Check for False as any value in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following dict:

```
default_wallart = {
    "parkinglot":False,
    "ferrari":False,
    "roadtrip":False,
    "sincity":False,
    "peekaboo":False
}
```

I update this to `True` when something happens and triggers it. What I would like to be able to do, though, is check if *any* of the values in the dict returns False (and if they do return False for any of the values do one thing, and if not, do something else).

So... how would I go about this? Would be nice if I could do this in a one-line check, but if not, I can work around that.

**Note:** this is for Python 2.7x

Comment: "check if *any* of the values" - did you try using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) (or `all`, as this is a negative check)? What *have* you tried?

Comment: I admit, I did not, because I didn't think of it at all. Problem with using simple words like "all" or "any", means that it's hard to search for - I did try searching for answers to my question, but only found vaguely similar, and way too complicated answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about doing

```
if all(default_wallart.values()):
    # All True
else:
    # At least one False.
```

---

It is worth mentioning that

```
>>> all({}.values()) # <=> all([])
True
```

So, pay attention to this possibility. Depending on what you want to do, you may want to check for `all(default_wallart.values()) and len(default_wallart)`

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I have a set dict, which will never be empty, and I only change from False to True, so no need for more rigourous checks. This is a non-mutable (in any way) dict, in a program, so if anyone mess this up, it's because they go poking in the source-code: ie, not my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that all values are either `True` or `False` then you could use `in` operator

```
default_wallart = {
    "parkinglot":False,
    "ferrari":False,
    "roadtrip":False,
    "sincity":False,
    "peekaboo":False
}
has_False = False in default_wallart.values()
print(has_False) #prints True if there is at least one False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not simply use the `all` builtin on the dictionary's values for this, because it will return `False` if it spots any *falsy* value such as `0`, `[]`, `{}`, ...

Demo:

```
>>> default_wallart = { 
...:     "parkinglot":1, 
...:     "ferrari":1, 
...:     "roadtrip":1, 
...:     "sincity":0, 
...:     "peekaboo":1 
...: }                                                                                                                            
>>>                                                                                                                               
>>> all(default_wallart.values())                                                                                                 
False
```

We need one more step, checking explicitly against `False`.

There is no `False`:

```
>>> all(x is not False for x in default_wallart.values())                                                                         
True
```

There is at least one `False`:

```
>>> any(x is False for x in default_wallart.values())                                                                             
False
```

(Checking against `True` or `False` with `is` is fine because these two are singletons.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
def do_something():
    return "do something"

def do_else():
    return "do else"


default_wallart = {
    "parkinglot":False,
    "ferrari":False,
    "roadtrip":False,
    "sincity":False,
    "peekaboo":False
}


result = do_something() if not all(default_wallart.itervalues()) else do_else()

print result
```

**Output**

```
do something
```